# Problem in Nearest Match Greater Than or Equal to the Search Key in Vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

How do I find the nearest match greater than or Equal to the Search Key in Vlookup?

I have tried this method, but it does not meet my requirements.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Vlookup(A2:A,{{1;Data!A2:A5},{Data!B2:B5;if(,,)}},2))
```

[Spreadsheets Demo Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YVnRuLed_FvO0fRMWms4GLNPdal3LmWpqUJNg5r_r-U/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Try this `=INDEX(XLOOKUP(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,""))`.

Comment: Then try `=INDEX(XLOOKUP(A2:A,Data!A2:A,Data!B2:B,"",-1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XLOOKUP()` with match mode parameter `-1` that indicated to search exact match or next lower values. Try-

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(A2:A,Data!A2:A,Data!B2:B,"",-1))
```

[image]